# Java 2D array for loop not reading the last value

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a school assignment and I'm having an issue with a 2d array. Basically my program takes an integer from the the user and determines if one of the array values is lower than that integer. I have a while and for loop set up to do the trick, but I can't seem to get my loop to use the last row of data. I've tried mixing things around for a couple of hours now.

I'm sure I'm derping really badly on whatever I'm missing, but I could use a hand now.
Here is the relevant data for my code

```
    //array of store inventory
    int invArray[][] = {{102, 54, 20, 78}, 
                        {45, 25, 35, 75},
                        {12, 35, 45, 65},
                        {54, 25, 34, 45},
                        {15, 35, 50, 25}};
    int menuChoice = 0;                     //allows user to select a menu option
    int storeNum=0;                         //store number
    String itemName="null";                 //name for an item
    int itemAmount=0;                       //items below this amount are pulled up in choice 4
    int arrayRow=0;                         //row value for invArray based on itemName
    int arrayCol=0;                         //column value for invArray based on storeNum


       //menu 4
        if (menuChoice == 4){
            System.out.print("Find all items below the number: ");

            //catches mistakes
            try{
            itemAmount = input.nextInt();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.print("Invalid value entered. Try again: ");
                itemAmount = input.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("Items below "+itemAmount+": ");

            //loop that checks item values at all stores
            arrayRow=0; 
            arrayCol=0;                         //counters for loop
            while (arrayCol < invArray[arrayRow].length){

                for (arrayRow = 0; arrayRow < invArray[arrayCol].length; arrayRow++){


                    if (invArray[arrayRow][arrayCol] < itemAmount){


                        if (arrayRow == 0)
                            itemName = "Tennis Shoes";
                        if (arrayRow == 1)
                            itemName = "Sweaters";
                        if (arrayRow == 2)
                            itemName = "Jeans";
                        if (arrayRow == 3)
                            itemName = "Shorts";
                        if (arrayRow == 4)
                            itemName = "Jackets";


                        //outputs stores with values lower than the one given
                        System.out.println("Store 10"+(arrayCol+1)+" "+itemName+": "
                        +invArray[arrayRow][arrayCol]);

                        for (int i = 0;invArray[4][i] < invArray[arrayRow].length; i++)
                            System.out.println("Store 10"+(i+1)+" "+" jackets : "+invArray[i][4]);
                    }


            }       
                arrayCol++;
                System.out.println();
        }//end item check loop
    }
```

Comment: Replacing `while (arrayCol < invArray[arrayRow].length)` by `while (arrayCol < invArray.length)` would make more sense. Not sure if that will solve your issue though.

Comment: `invArray[whatever].length` will be the number of columns ( = 4), not the number of rows ( = 5). Which means you'll only read 4 * 4 = 16 elements, and you won't get to the last row.

Comment: Whenever I remove the [] fields from either .lengths I get an out of bounds error

Comment: @user1462585 Switch the variables arrayCol and arrayRow only in your for loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong second loop. It should be

```
for (arrayRow = 0; arrayRow < invArray.length; arrayRow++){
```

since `arrayRow` is the first index. In you code you get 4 instead of 5 which causes an error.

Also you would better use `for` for both loops.

And also you should better have column loop inside row loop, since former is dependent, or you should exchange indices;

Comment: Did exactly what you suggested and it worked! Just needed to add an exception for an out of bounds error. I wanted to keep the format as rows inside columns so I could list the item quantity at each particular store, but I'ld rather have the thing work! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while (arrayRow < invArray.length) {
    for (arrayCol = 0; arrayCol < invArray[arrayRow].length; arrayCol++) {
        //...
    }
    arrayRow++;
}
```

Your array has dimensions `[4][5]`; you're switching the two and trying to access an element as if the array had dimensions `[5][4]`. You're also only accessing 16 elements since `invArray[a].length` will always be 4 for all `a` that work.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you need the second line

```
itemName = "Jackets";
arrayCol++;
```

bur your code confuses me a bit, so i am not sure if this solves.

Comment: I was trying all sorts of random things to get the 5th line to read. I guess I didn't clean my code up all the way before I posted it here.